# Looking the `ember` way for `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` for iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, ember.js

currently I am developing the app for both desktop and mobile. I use:

```
<span onMouseEnter={{action 'toolInfoHandler' index }} onMouseLeave={{action 'toolInfoHandler' }}>
                        <!--info icon -->
                    </span>
```

it's works fine for desktop. But I am not finding a way to `iphone` since it's not behave as expected.

here is my action:

```
actions:{
        setDuration:function(trans, data, options){
            Ember.set(options, 'selected', data);
            Ember.set(trans, 'duration', data);
            this.setMonthlyInstallment(trans, data );
        },
        toolInfoHandler:function(index){
            this.set('selectedIndex',  index);
        },
        shuffleFootNotes(){
            this.toggleProperty('ic2bFootNotes');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually I showing and hiding a tool tip and the mouseenter and mouseleave event

Comment: Well, I'd the same issue. I did it with `mouseEnter` & `mouseLeave` for desktop; `touchStart` & `blur` for touch screens (mobile). Actually you may prefer `touchCancel` instead of `blur` for your case.

Comment: I agree. But how can i implement that? do you want me to add both events in action?

Comment: You may prefer like that. [Here is a twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a4b0187ba5b8ff68f13a1f27bc55b9d0?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) I've prepared for you.

Comment: @ykaragol can't I use your approach in `controller`?

Comment: AFAIK these event handlers are defined in components.

Comment: Is there any workaround for controller? since i am not use any component with me now

Comment: Add `onTouchCancel` and `onBlur` event to your `<span>` tag.

Comment: Don't avoid using components. They're extremely powerful and intended for just this kind of functionality. Just put a component in your route template and utilize the hooks in the twiddle.